# Can I change the phrase "OK Google Now" to something else?

Tags: voice-command, google-voice-actions, moto-x

I want to say a different name or phrase when I wake up my Moto X android.

Is there any way, or hack that I can use to change the name?

Ideally I don't want to "root" the phone because I don't know what that does and think that opens me up to security issues.

Comment: For what it's worth, it seems the magic phrase is now just "OK Google". Supposedly, "OK Jarvis" (aka, the computer from Iron Man) works as well.

Answer (score 2):

[Apparently](http://forums.androidcentral.com/motorola-droid-maxx/308651-changing-ok-google-now.html) you can use the training software it includes and just train it to hear something else. As in, if it says "read this: " just say whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the attempts described in Louis's post [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/62414/hotword-detection-of-google-now-search-not-woking), but they have limited success.

As of now, there is no way to change the Touchless Control hotword to anything you want, but as per the "hack" you requested, using [AutoVoice](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autovoice&hl=en) with [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) would be the way to go. You can set up AutoVoice to listen continuously for any hotword you want, then use that hotword through tasker to trigger Google Now. A tutorial for the setup can be found [here](http://www.pocketables.com/2013/05/how-to-use-google-now-from-autovoice-using-autoshare-and-tasker.html) that also uses [AutoShare](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoshare&hl=en).

Be aware that this workaround won't give voice responses, as it essentially records your voice and uses the input to do a text search. If I find a more usable example, I'll share it here, but this may be as good as can be done without root.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but I found out that you can not change that phrase. I tried to but in the settings there is no option, only the enable and disable. It would be great if they did that but Google is not yet so modern. Hope Google fixes that problem because it would be great. We need to wait a few more years and hopefully this problem would be changed. Sorry everyone who wanted to change the phrase or the quote on their computer,laptop,iphone or android.

Answer (score 1):

Moto X users (and possibly others) can now change the phrase to anything they want with the 5.0.2 updates that was just released.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Open Mic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.RSen.OpenMic.Pheonix) from the Google Play Store

Comment: This answer might be helpful if you add a link to the app you're recommending. Also, please confirm what relationship (if any) you have with this app: it's OK to recommend your own app on this site, provided you're honest about it.

Comment: **[OpenMic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.RSen.OpenMic.Pheonix&hl=en)** and **[OpenMic + Donate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.RSen.OpenMic.Pheonix.Donate&hl=en)** has a constant media beep which goes on continuously and interrupts other mic-based applications. Check it out @DanHulme. I don't think it's worth it.

Answer (score -2):

I use KitKat 4.4, Moto X.

You CANNOT use any phrase you wish. I tried, and it does not work.