# Hotword detection of google now / search not woking

Tags: google-now, voice-recognition, google-search

After switching to a new ROM I restored Google Now using Titanium backup but however I no longer have hotword detection enabled neither do I have the option to enable it (It is simply missing)!

It used to say *Search, or say "OK Google"* but now it only says *Search*

However, speech recognition in general works fine!

**Other relevant information:**

- Using Samsung Galaxy SII
- Using Vivek ROM but experienced same problem on CyanogenMod

Answer (score 1):

**Solved it!**

I realised that I had set Language to 'English(UK)' (under 'voice' settings of the Google Now app) and apparently hotword detection currently works only with English(US) (In my case, the offline voice recognition package I had installed was 'English(US)' , but language was English(UK) )!

**Solution:**

So a simple switching of 'Language' to English(US) will do the trick!

It is a little funny, who would have guessed English(US) and English(UK) are considered completely different languages!

**By the way:**

I tried downloading and installing English(UK) as my offline voice recognition language and then switching the Language as well to English(UK) **BUT** it didn't work, hotword detection stopped working again. This means Hotword detection only works with English(US) irrespective of whether you have other offline voice recognition packages installed as well!

Comment: You don't need to put edits in an "edit" section. Your answer would be most useful if you just make the correction; as it stands, the answer tells people the wrong thing, and then says it's wrong.

Comment: Will keep in mind...(fixed solution)