# No Google Now Hotword Detection on Moto X

Tags: google-now, moto-x, ok-google

I've checked [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/62414/hotword-detection-of-google-now-search-not-woking) solution, but it hasn't worked for me.

After updating to 4.4, my Moto X Google Now has lost the "OK Google" hotword function. "OK Google Now" on the Moto X system still works, but I like being able to do another search in Google Now without having to leave that environment again (it's much faster than doing "OK Google Now" through Touchless Control).

My mic icon in Google Now shows up "unfilled," (example below) and I have Hotword detection enabled and am using English (US).

Ideas?

[image]

Comment: Wasn't it "OK Moto" on those Motorola devices? Just a curious question, I've got no deeper knowledge in that area.

Comment: Doesn't work for me :/ That would be cool though!!

Answer (score 0):

According to Google+ community comments from multiple people, Chrome Beta browser has this effect. Uninstall Chrome Beta and begin using normal Chrome to fix it.

Comment: Got a source to back this up?

Comment: Don't have Chrome Beta installed, just default Chrome