# Phone reacts to "OK" without "Google"

Tags: google-now, voice-recognition

I need to change the voice command from OK Google to something else. It reacts to my voice in meetings when I answer OK. That is a problem!!

Comment: Do you have  the "OKGoogle from lock screen" option turned on? Disabling it if it's on should solve your meeting problem.  As for changing the OK Google phrase try [Open Mic+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.RSen.OpenMic.Pheonix) (it's free despite the '+' :) )

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/55447/can-i-change-the-phrase-ok-google-now-to-something-else